# How to covert a c++ enum vector to an equivalent Objective C array/vector?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, arrays, enums

I am using a C++ library on an iOS app. One of the functions provides me with an `std::vector` that contains C enums. I would like to use this data in Objective C (not Object C++) and hence I am required to convert this array to an equivalent Objective C data structure. I am using a bridging class that converts C++ to Objective C.

My code looks somewhat like:

```
typedef enum 
{  
  Error0 = 0,
  Error1 = 1,
  Error2 = 2
} MyError;

class ListenerImpl : public Listener
{
public:
    ListenerImpl(Listener* listener) : _listener(listener) {}
    void onError(std::vector<MyError> errors) override
    {
        // Calling Objective C listener (listener class should not be using Objective C++)
        [_listener onError:convertToObjC(errors)];
    }

    void handleError(MyError error, int someExtraData) {
        // Error values are returned back to C++ so if any mapping is to be used it needs to be bi-directional.
    }
private:

    // The question is how to implement this function and what is a good return value here.
    ArrayRetValue convertToObjC(std::vector<MyError> & errors) 
    { 
        // Not sure how to accomplish this
    }
    __weak Listener* _listener;
}
```

My question is: **How can implement this in a maintainable way?**

Comment: What's the interface of `ArrayRetValue`?

Comment: That is part of the question. I am uncertain what would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much consideration, I've decided to use a combination of an NSArray and generics. This way, I can be explicit about the data and I won't have to worry about possible memory leaks with a C array as I am using Objective-C objects.

To achieve this, I had to create an Objective-C equivalent object for my C enum (as NSArray requires a type). Hence I created `ErrorEnumObj`.

Here is the full solution:

```
typedef enum 
{  
  Error0 = 0,
  Error1 = 1,
  Error2 = 2
} MyError;

@interface ErrorEnumObj : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) int intValue;

+ (instancetype) objWithEnum:(MyError) myError;
- (MyError) getEnumValue;

@end 

@implementation ErrorEnumObj

+ (instancetype) objWithEnum:(MyError) error
{
    ErrorEnumObj * obj = [ErrorEnumObj new];
    obj.intValue = (int)error;
    return obj;
}

- (MyError) getEnumValue
{
    return (MyError)self.intValue;
}

@end

class ListenerImpl : public Listener
{
public:
    ListenerImpl(Listener* listener) : _listener(listener) {}
    void onError(std::vector<MyError> errors) override
    {
        NSMutableArray<ErrorEnumObj *> * array = [NSMutableArray<ErrorEnumObj *> new]; 
        for (auto&& myError : errors)
        {
            [array addObject:[ErrorEnumObj objWithEnum:myError]];
        }
        [_listener onError:array];
    }

private:
    __weak Listener* _listener;
}
```

If this kind of solution is to be used on multiple enums, the creation of the EnumObj (declaration & implementation) can be done using a macro (to create a template like solution).

Answer (score 0):

In .h file:

```
#if __OBJC__
typedef NSArray *ArrayRetValue;
#else
typedef void *ArrayRetValue;
#endif
```

In .mm file (you need it to mix C++ and Obj-C code):

```
NSMutableArray * ListenerImpl::convertToObjC(std::vector<MyError> & errors) 
{
    NSMutableArray *objCErrors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:errors.size()];
    for (auto error: errors) {
        [objCErrors addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:error]];
    }
    return objCErrors;
}
```

Also you need to move `onError` function to the .mm file too, or you will not be able to use this class in C++ code.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that whenever I am using the array I have to cast the NSNumber back into the enum (for example in a switch case). In addition, it is not explicit that the content of the array is only MyError values.